# Visual Studio 2017: Xamarin Previewer not working - Unsatisfied Link Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-previewer

I'm just trying around with Xamarin on Visual Studio 2017 but it seems that the previewer is not working. I looked up in the for solutions for this put unfortunate none of the solutions I found works.
This is the error I got:

```
Trying to load class md5e940e1e778de0f856e343395a2f338c5.XFPageRendererView
>mono.android.DesignerException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError
    at mono.android.DesignerException.fromThrowable(DesignerException.java:46)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.checkRenderResultForError(DesignerSession.java:187)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:239)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:702)
    at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
    at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: md5e940e1e778de0f856e343395a2f338c5.XFPageRendererView.n_onMeasure(II)V
    at md5e940e1e778de0f856e343395a2f338c5.XFPageRendererView.n_onMeasure(Native Method)
    at md5e940e1e778de0f856e343395a2f338c5.XFPageRendererView.onMeasure(XFPageRendererView.java:54)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19734)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureView(RenderSessionImpl.java:589)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:342)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:233)
    ... 4 more
```

The JDK-Path for Xamarin win Visual Studio is set to a 64-bit 1.8 JDK.
I'm using the Package Xamarin.Android.Support.* in Version 25.3.1
and Xamarin.Forms in Version 2.3.4.247.

Does anyone know something about this issue?

Also additional question: Why isn't there a previewer for windows phone or just windows?

Comment: Previewer seems to be retired. In VS2017 preview Xamarin demonstrated LivePlayer. I couldn't make any of them working

Comment: @YuriS Seems to be an overcomplicated solution and still missing any kind of previewer or design time view for Windows (Desktop, Tablet or Phone). Well seems that I have to live with: Change XAML, compile & start on Windows and Android Emulator.